# NavigationView closes instantly

Tags: android, kotlin, navigationview

When I try to open the NavigationView, it closes instantly so as it's not even shown at all. When I double click to open it, it shows for a brief second before closing again.

My MainActivity class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayoutprivate lateinit var navigationView: NavigationView
```

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val toolbar: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout)
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView)

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()


    setupNavigation()
}

private fun setupNavigation() {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.quickAlarm -> showQuickAlarmFragment()
            R.id.alarmList -> showAlarmListFragment()
            R.id.info -> showInfoFragment()
        }
        true
    }
}

private fun showQuickAlarmFragment() {
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, QuickAlarmFragment.newInstance())
        .commit()
}

private fun showAlarmListFragment() {
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, AlarmListFragment.newInstance())
        .commit()
}

private fun showInfoFragment() {
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, InfoFragment.newInstance())
        .commit()
}
```

```
}
```

My activity_main.xml:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"android:layout_width="match_parent"android:layout_height="match_parent"><LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

```
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"/>
```

```
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I tried to implement a regular NavigationView but it closes instantly before it's shown.

Comment: It's not clear what the specific problem is. Do you mean that you can't get the drawer open? If so, how are you trying to open it, exactly? The toggle button only needs a single click. You can also drag it open, but that can be a little tricky.

Comment: The toggle button doesn't work. More precisely, it works but the drawer opens only for a moment making it seem like it doesn't open at all.

Comment: Well, I can't see anything that might explain the observed behavior, and my run of your posted example works as expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlQ5t.png. Are you sure the code here is exactly what you're running currently? Have you cleaned/rebuilt your project lately, just to be sure?

Comment: Just a clean/rebuild solved the problem! Didn't think it could be the solution. Thank you.